# MySQL sum of column value from derived table

Tags: mysql, join, sum, case

This is my query:

```
SELECT usr.id,
       count(DISTINCT sol.id) as 'Asked',
       count(DISTINCT ans.id) as 'Answered',
       sum(DISTINCT CASE ans.accepted WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as 'Accepted'
FROM tbl_users usr
LEFT JOIN tbl_solutions sol on sol.authorID = usr.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_solution_answers ans on ans.authorID = usr.id
group by usr.id, sol.authorID
```

My above query with the `sum(DISTINCT CASE ans.accepted WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)` only ever returns 1 though I know that's not the case. I've tried adding a group clause on the `ans.authorID` but it has no effect.

How can I get the sum of all rows from the `tbl_solution_answers ans` table where the `authorID` is that of `tbl_users.id` and `Accepted` is 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT usr.id,
   count(DISTINCT sol.id) as 'Asked',
   count(DISTINCT ans.id) as 'Answered',
   count(DISTINCT case ans.accepted when 1 then ans.id end) as 'Accepted'
FROM tbl_users usr
LEFT JOIN tbl_solutions sol on sol.authorID = usr.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_solution_answers ans on ans.authorID = usr.id
group by usr.id, sol.authorID, ans.authorID
```

After so many permutations `count(DISTINCT case ans.accepted when 1 then ans.id end) as 'Accepted'` seems to work. Now if an `authorID` in `tbl_solution_answers` has 8 rows they'll all be returned as `Answered` and if say 3 of them are `Accepted` then 3 is returned as `Accepted`.